# What does 'Could not find a log backup file that could be applied' means on log shipping?

Tags: sql-server-2012, log-shipping

> Skipped Log Backup File ..... Could not find a log backup file that
>   could be applied to secondary Database

[image]

What does this mean?

I've configured a log shipping. To test, I created 2 tables, put values on them, created another 2 and etc.

During the first run of the job, is says the message above.

Later, let's say after 2 or 3 runs, the log shipping starts to modify the secondary database.

Why this happens during the firsts runs?

Even if I use `checkpoint` I see that error.

In this post [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106195/sql-server-log-shipping-randomly-stops-copying-and-restoring) Says something:

> The Restore job finds no suitable log files to apply in location B
>   because they are all being backed up to location A and NOT being
>   copied over to B (due to the Copy job being disabled).

I'm with 2 windows oppened and I can see both jobs working ( I can see the backup log job ( because I can see files being created )), and I can see the copy is working too ( files are being created on the second window too).

And, a bonus question...I want to log shipping from `SQL 2012` to `SQL 2014`. So, I need to use "no recovery" option right? because I can't use `stand by` with a higher version on the secondary. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Are you still in sync?  Log shipping happens in phases and isn't instantaneous, as you are observing.  I've seen it take > 45 minutes before an actual restore occurs on the secondary.  You can check this by right clicking on the instance name, Reports -> Standard Reports -> Transaction Log Shipping Status.  As to the bonus question, you are correct, if you recover the DBs, their version numbers will upgrade and log shipping will not be able to bring the DB back to a NORECOVERY/Restoring... state.

Comment: Yes it's in sync. i'm now testing from `2012` to `2014`. The job is running each minute. it took more than 5 minutes to receive the `The restore operation was successful. Secondary Database: 'banco_secundario', Number of log backup files restored: 1`. And according to the report, is everything ok.